# Getting id errors when trying to delete tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am extremely new to ruby on rails and I was following a tutorial to set up a simple blog style website. I had implemented tags on the articles but now I'm getting errors when trying to implement the deleting of tags. I think this is where the error is coming from.

```
def destroy

@tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
@tag.destroy

flash.notice = "Tag '#{@tag.name}' Deleted!"

redirect_to action: "index"

end
```

I think it's the line @tag = Tag.find(params[:id]) that's causing the following error:

Couldn't find Tag with 'id'=#< Tag::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fdd2c016ba0>

I'm stuck with this because I managed to implement the deleting of articles in this way so I'm unsure as to why this won't work.

Edit:
This is the view file.

```
<h1>All Tags</h1>

<ul id="tags">
   <% @tag.each do |tag| %>
   <li>
    <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag) %>

    <%= link_to "delete", tag_path(@tag), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Really delete the tag?"} %>

  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: post your view file from where you pass the params to destroy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `@tag` to `tag` you are passing an array instead of single value..

```
<ul id="tags">
   <% @tag.each do |tag| %>
   <li>
    <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag) %>

    <%= link_to "delete", tag_path(tag), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Really delete the tag?"} %>

  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks for spotting my stupid mistake!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the tag variable instead of the @tag variable in the tag_path method in your view.

```
 <%= link_to "delete", tag_path(tag), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Really delete the tag?"} %>
```